# Can't run headless chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

**System environment:**

- JVM 11.0.6-open
- ubuntu 18.04
- SDKMAN 5.8.1+484
- Gradle 6.1
- Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138
- Chrome driver 3.141.59

**Code to run:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

4:52:09 PM: Executing task 'Runner.main()'...

> Task :compileJava
>   Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
>   Task :classes
>
> Task :Runner.main()
>   error: unknown flag `port'
>   May 14, 2020 4:52:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
>   SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>   System info: host: '****', ip: '*.*.*.*', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.3.0-46-generic', java.version: '11.0.6'
>   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>       at Runner.main(Runner.java:19)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:13284/status] to be available after 20004 ms
>       at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
>       ... 10 more
>
> Task :Runner.main() FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':Runner.main()'.

  > Process 'command '/home/***/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
4:52:30 PM: Task execution finished 'Runner.main()'.

Comment: Which version of chrome and chrome driver are you using? It sounds like a version mismatch.

Comment: Also, which port is the selenium server attempting to use? Is there another process already using that port?

Comment: @GregBurghardt probably, that is not my case.
 
I managed to fix it. 
Removing this line of code makes it work.


`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver");`

I do not really understand how driver is consumed by my system

Comment: @GregBurghardt One more thing, in my case server even could not be started. On the other hand, it is perfectly fine if I run it manually

Comment: Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138, 
Chrome driver 3.141.59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade your ChromeDriver to match the major version of your Chrome browser:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

You will probably want version 81.0.4044.138.